# In IntelliJ from snap I can't select openJDK 11 from apt-get

Tags: java, jdk, openjdk, 18.10, intellij

I am using Ubuntu 18.10 64 bit.

I have installed IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.1 via snap.

I have installed openJDK 11.0.1 with apt-get.

I now want to set openJDK as the SDK for IntelliJ.

However when I try to select `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64` the error

> The selected directory is not a valid home for JDK

occurs.

But the directory exists and its `bin` folder contains the `java` executable.

What am I doing wrong? Which other location could I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have switched to Oracle's official JDK and now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue on 18.04, 64 Bit, only to find out, that I did not install the JDK properly. The path was referring to the JRE instead. Did you check for the `javac` (!) executable in the `bin` directory ? Mine was not in the directory (`/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin`).

I did a

```
apt-get update 
apt-get install openjdk-11-jdk
```

After that IntelliJ recognized the JDK automatically. Hope that helps, good luck !